# Custom error object not correctly rendered in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have created a custom Error object:

```
function DialogException(message, data) {
    this.name = "DialogException";
    this.message = message;
    this.data = data;
}

DialogException.prototype = new Error();
DialogException.prototype.constructor = DialogException;
```

This is the reccomended way of doing it (right?):
[[MDN JavaScript Refference]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types)

When throwing this Error:

```
throw new DialogException('Missing Dialog Settings (dialogDescriptor.dialog).');
```

Firefox console is showing it this way:

[image: Firefox Console]

Google Chrome Console is showing it that way:

[image: Chrome Console]

Can someone please explain why Chrome does not render the custom error object correctly?  I would expect an output like the one from Firefox.

- Chrome Version: 26.0.1410.64 m
- Firefox Version: 19.0.2

Comment: Executing this code in the Chrome developer tools logs `DialogException: ViewModel is missing (dialogDescriptor.viewModel).` So it is working correctly in version 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: @JohannesLumpe Strange, executing it directly in the console gives me the same result as you got.  But calling that same code from within my JavaScript function renders the incorrect output...

Comment: not sure why that would happen - can't really test right now, but here is a suggestion: add a 'toString' method to the prototype and return `this.name +':'+ this.message`.